# CONVERT ALL COLUMNS TO ROWS

Tags: sql, oracle

My query:

```
select * from some_table where id = 4045432
```

returns a single row with 60+ columns. I shouldn't depend on column names (because column names change often and I have to get all the data "as is" without updating sql query every time)

What I want is to change all columns to rows like:

```
COLUMN|VALUE 
=============
C1|V1
C2|V2
```

How I may achieve this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably need to use some dynamic SQL in order to achieve your goal.

You can use Oracle's `UNPIVOT` keyword to turn a short-fat table with many columns into a tall-skinny result set with `COLUMN` / `VALUE` pairs.

Here's an example, based on the venerable `EMP` table:

```
select empno, col, val from 
(
  -- This query needs to convert all columns to a common datatype
  select empno, ename, job, to_char(sal) sal, to_char(comm) comm, to_char(hiredate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') hiredate, to_char(deptno) deptno
    from emp
)
unpivot
(
  val for col
  in(
    ename,
    job,
    sal,
    comm,
    hiredate,
    deptno
   )
)
```

This produces pretty much what you are looking for:

```
EMPNO COL      VAL
----- -------- ----------
7839  ENAME    KING
7839  JOB      PRESIDENT
7839  SAL      5000
7839  HIREDATE 1981-11-17
7839  DEPTNO   10
...
```

You would probably need to include the primary key of the table as a column (like `EMPNO` here) in order for the data to make sense.

Note that the datatypes had to be converted. The `UNPIVOT` mechanism won't work if you are trying to unpivot dates, numbers, and text all at once.
Because of this, your PL/SQL would possibly have to do some work in querying `DBA_TAB_COLS` or `USER_TAB_COLS` and building up the query with appropriate conversions.

For 60+ columns this could be tedious, but it would be a one-time effort that would work on other wide tables.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do without the hazel of writing all column names in the select statement is by using dynamic sql.
Any changes to the underlying query(Tablename/Filter) wouldn't require to add relevant column names in the select statement as that will be taken care by dynamic sql.

Create the table:

```
create table match_results (
  match_date       date,
  location         varchar2(20),
  home_team_name   varchar2(20),
  away_team_name   varchar2(20),
  home_team_points integer,
  away_team_points integer
);
```

Insert a row:

```
insert into match_results values ( date'2018-01-01', 'Snowley', 'Underrated United', 'Terrible Town', 2, 0 );
```

Pl/sql Block to convert rows to column :

```
declare 

plsql_block VARCHAR2(500);
lv_col_value VARCHAR2(500);

begin 


dbms_output.put_line('ColumnName|Value');

for v1 in (select column_name 
            from user_tab_columns where table_name ='MATCH_RESULTS'
           order by column_id)
 loop
    
    --Add filter as desired but restrict result set to one row
    plsql_block := 'select ' || v1.column_name  || ' from MATCH_RESULTS Where LOCATION = ''Snowley'' and rownum < 2';

    execute immediate plsql_block into lv_col_value;
    dbms_output.put_line(v1.column_name||'| '||lv_col_value);

 end loop;

end;
/
```

PS: The only downside is that the pl/sql block loops through total number of column times to fetch just single row, considering the use case it doesn't have any impact.And of course it is pl/sql and not sql.

Output:

```
1 rows affected

dbms_output:
ColumnName|Value
MATCH_DATE| 01-JAN-18
LOCATION| Snowley
HOME_TEAM_NAME| Underrated United
AWAY_TEAM_NAME| Terrible Town
HOME_TEAM_POINTS| 2
AWAY_TEAM_POINTS| 0
```

Refer DBfiddle demo @https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c8330c410e59504d03606c4d370f30d9